# Cannot Join Domain by Name but can Ping DC IP and Domain Name

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain, dhcp

I am trying to connect a Windows 7 client to a Domain, the Domain was created on Windows 2012 Server (Core Version) and is fully working on that.

From the Win 7 Client, I can Ping "10.0.0.2" and "xyz.com", but I cannot seem to Join the Domain.

The following error occurs:

[image: Could Not Be contacted Error]

Also the Win 7 Client IP is in the same range as the DC (Client - 10.0.0.20) and (DC - 10.0.0.2)

And the Client DNS IP is set to the Servers IP.

Comment: Can you ping your DC by its DNS name, dc.xyz.com? Can you resolve it? If the answer is no, check your DNS for your DC record; if the answer is yes, you might miss your DC SRV records in the DNS.

Comment: More things popping out of my mind: is the AD DS service running in your DC? It might be stopped for some reason. Or blocked by the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Obviously, if you're resolving DNS, next step is to check win firewall, ensure that the ports necessary for the AD are open or failing that I guess you can disable it although not recommended. Core, especialy 2008 R2 and older is notorious for not always activating ports its supposed to

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same issue. And it's solved by check DNS settings on the client. Write your DC ip address in the client DNS box and reboot to make it effect.

Comment: OP already said he tried that, plus the client is able to resolve the address (see ping). So it isn't a DNS problem, more likely a firewall or service related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Coming into this a little bit late but it seems like the user can ping by IP address and can ping the domain, but they don't mention if they can ping the DC server by shortname, so that combined with the error message lead me to believe it IS a DNS issue. This can be resolved by adding the DNS suffix under the DNS tab of the Advanced options for the IPvX settings on the NIC of the affected computer(s).

You should also be able to add the domain controller IP and shortname to the affected computer(s)'s hosts file to resolve this.

Hope this helps from 5 years in the future!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue by disabling the IPv6 from the Ethernet adapter.

When I was doing a nslookup to my domain it was resolving an IPv6 instead if the IP address of my domain.